# Timer function crashes app

Tags: swift, crash

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func runTimedCode() {

  imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card10")
}

}
```

This code gives me the message "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but i do not know what the problem is. Can someone please help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var timer: Timer? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func runTimedCode() {

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card10")
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how this fixes it.

Comment: @rmaddy - I'm guessing the issue has something to do with initialization and using self before being fully initialized, but I didn't want to put a reason down unless I was sure it was right. otherwise, I'd have you and matt putting comments "this is wrong" and possibly insinuating something insulting...I've had you guys downvote me before for having one detail of a correct answer slightly off, so I'd rather leave unsure parts out. if you have a better  answer, then I invite you to post it.

Comment: Your explanation needs to be in your answer, not a comment.

Comment: Well one problem is that a view controller is instantiated before its `view` has been, and thus the outlet is likely to be `nil`, and an implicitly unwrapped optional will crash if you use it while it is `nil`. Besides, there's no point in updating an image view that isn't present yet.

Comment: By the way, this code manifests a bug, namely, that this recurring timer will prevent the view controller from ever being released. I'd suggest moving the timer into `viewDidAppear` and then add the `invalidate` of the timer in `viewDidDisappear`, that way, the timer won't keep strong reference on the view controller. And this solves the OPs problem, just like your example above. (Or, btw, you could use the block-based rendition of repeating timer with `[weak self]` qualifier and invalidate in `deinit`.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the function like bellow.

```
 var timer:Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

     @objc func runTimedCode(){

print("timer is calling")
  }
```

Comment: This (a) has nothing to do with the problem above; (b) the  `#selector(ViewController.runTimedCode)` syntax is fine; and (c) the `self.` is redundant and could be simplified to `#selector(runTimedCode)`.